# How to create chrome profile via Ruby Selenium Binding(or WATIR)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I know how to create profile for Firefox

```
require 'watir'
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
options.profile = "default"
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options
@b = Watir::Browser.new @driver
```

But when I do same thing for Chrome it's not creating, Infact I realized that options(please look above) object doesn't even have the method `profile=` so I try adding profile like as given below(I saw how people are creating in Java Selenium Binding so I have done the same but it's not working here)

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default')
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Can someone help me how to create Chrome Profile via Ruby Selenium binding(or WATIR)?

Comment: I am not sure about RUBY , but are you open for JAVA  or Python ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I know to do it in Java, I don't know how to do it in Ruby, that's what the question is.

Comment: I am not sure what applies to Watir, but when setting up Capybara (another framework for automated gui tests), we needed to do set the browser_options (of type `::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new`) to `--headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox`. Maybe this helps

Comment: @JaySchneider I know capybara, Can you write the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an existing or creating a new profile can be done via Chromedrivers user-data-dir argument. In Watir, you can pass the argument via the `:args` parameter:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, 
  args: ['user-data-dir=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data']
```

Note that if you trying to use the existing default profile, you do not want to include the "Default" directory in the path.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Justin!

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for creating new browser. You can use it.

```
 def new_browser
  if Rails.env.production?
    chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "/app/vendor/bundle/bin/chromedriver"
  end


  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10'

  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :profile => profile
  pid = driver.instance_variable_get(:@service).instance_variable_get(:@process).instance_variable_get(:@pid)

  begin
    browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
  rescue => e
    system("kill -9 #{@pid}")
  end
  return {:browser => browser , :pid => pid}
end
```

Comment: What is this? Where you are setting chrome profile? where is the path? It's not working for me, Profile is not being set by your code.

Comment: i think this is chrome profile
{profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10'}
Then this profile is used in webdriver .

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked in the comments for a more detailed explanation for Capybara, I post it as an answer (although you seem to already have a working solution now - sorry for the delayed answer).

In my rails projects I usually configure the Selenium chrome driver as follows:

```
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
```

in the Gemfile (or install it locally). Then in a system-test initializer define

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless_no_sandbox do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  browser_options.args << '--headless'
  browser_options.args << '--disable-gpu'
  browser_options.args << '--no-sandbox'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end
```

and later (configuring RSpec) I set it as the used driver like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless_no_sandbox
  end
end
```

Maybe this helps someone. Cheers

*edit: added chromedriver-helper*

Comment: Thank you, but I keep wondering how it works? Can you please look at JustinKo answer where he included the directory path for profile!

Comment: I forgot to mention I use the chromedriver-helper gem. I edited the answer. Maybe try if this works for you?