# Disable/Enable Pop up blocker in Chrome Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium

How can I disable/enable pop up blocker in Chrome webdriver using Ruby?

I need to disable the pop up blocker in chrome and validate the text in new window

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you seen `options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')` yet? [docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#command-line-switches)

Comment: Use a [custom profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203159/3784008).

Comment: Hi Use WATIR if you ready to take Ruby selenium binding for your automation because WATIR is a nice wrapper for Ruby Selenium Binding.